# If without braces for how many statements it works?

Tags: php

OK, I got the answer. It was not so clear to me in PHP documentation. Thanks

I know, this question is simple, but I unfortunately I cannot answer it by myself :(

So, the question is, when some developer uses the `if` statement without braces, for how many lines next to if statement the if works?

More specific, let's say I have the following code:

```
if(1 == 1)
    SayHello();
    SayYourName('Nikos');
    SayYourAge(32);
```

Will all of this function calls be executed if the `1` is equal to `1`? Or will it execute only the first one?

Comment: Did you find neither the official documentation nor any of the tutorials useful?

Comment: Is that documented ? :? I just google it :( and I didn't found any answer that satisfy my question :( Let me see again

Comment: it only work for first line...but it will also run second and third line too.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+if+statement => http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: @DipeshParmar if you like give an answer. Thanks

Comment: most difficult question till date !!!!

Comment: such code execution construct is native to all c based languages, how can u possibly have missed it

Comment: i think this is the first or second page in every programming tutorial. how can you ask if this is documented? so all the people in the world dont really know how to use if?

Comment: http://www.php.net/if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` condition without `{}` will only execute first statement, In your case.

```
if(1 == 1)
    SayHello();
    SayYourName('Nikos');
    SayYourAge(32);
```

`SayHello();` will only be executed when if condition will satisfy now other two line will also execute.

You can find nice explanation [**here**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no)

Answer (score 3):

Only one line that is below the if condition is executed against the if condition.

Comment: this is a really bad answer, you are saying that only the first is going to be executed and thats obviusly not true. anyways i cant believe the question

Comment: My answer says that the if condition is applied to only the line below the if statement. By default rest of the code is executed.

Comment: now it is clear. you was assuming too much, considering how the question is!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use multiple statement after if statement without "{" brace you can use:

```
if(1):
     SayHello();
     SayYourName('Nikos');
     SayYourAge(32);
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

> When using if statements without the curly braces, remember than only
>   one statement will be executed as part of that condition. If you want
>   to place multiple statements you must use curly braces, and not just
>   put them on the same line.

Please try googling or searching the documentation before posting questions. It actually helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

only one line right after the conditional statement will be executed.